# How to fix LevelDB library load error when running RSKj node on a Windows machine?

Tags: rsk

I am trying to run RSK blockchain node RSKj on a Windows machine. When I run this line in a terminal:

```sh
C:\Users\yemode> java -cp C:\Users\yemode\Downloads\Programs\rskj-core-3.0.1-IRIS-all.jar  co.rsk.Start
```

the RSKj node starts running, but I get the following error:

```sh
Cannot load secp256k1 native library: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Windows and os.arch=x86. path=/org/bitcoin/native/Windows/x86
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't initialize database
        at org.ethereum.datasource.LevelDbDataSource.init(LevelDbDataSource.java:110)
        at org.ethereum.datasource.LevelDbDataSource.makeDataSource(LevelDbDataSource.java:70)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildTrieStore(RskContext.java:1015)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildAbstractTrieStore(RskContext.java:935)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.getTrieStore(RskContext.java:416)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildRepositoryLocator(RskContext.java:1057)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.getRepositoryLocator(RskContext.java:384)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.getTransactionPool(RskContext.java:353)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildInternalServices(RskContext.java:829)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildNodeRunner(RskContext.java:821)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.getNodeRunner(RskContext.java:302)
        at co.rsk.Start.main(Start.java:34)
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a warning, not an error, though it may seem like the latter. This means that on your OS and architecture, that particular library does not exist, so it falls back to a different implementation (using a non-native library). In this case, the block verification is slower, but otherwise RSKj should continue to function properly.

Something that might help you to overcome the “slowness” of the initial sync is the `--import` flag. See the [reference in the CLI docs for RSKj](https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/node/configure/cli/#database-related).

Also you can send an RPC to ensure that your node is running OK. Run the following `curl` command in your terminal

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H “Content-Type:application/json” \
  --data ‘{“jsonrpc”:“2.0",“method”:“eth_blockNumber”,“params”:[],“id”:67}’ \
  http://localhost:4444
```

The response should be similar to this one

```json
{“jsonrpc”:“2.0",“id”:67,“result”:“0x2b12”}
```

where the `result` is your last block number

Comment: I would also suggest that you re-query that same RPC after a few minute to check that the block number has increased. This ensures that the RSK node is indeed fetching and validating new blocks, thereby verifying that the persistent store (using whichever implementation) is functioning.